# draw fog of war using shaders

Tags: opengl, shaders, graphics, fog-of-war

I am making a RTS game, and I'd like some advice on how to best render fog of wars, given what I'm already doing.

You can imagine this game as being a classic RTS like Age of Empires 2, where the fog of war will basically be handled by a 2D array telling if a given "tile" is explored or not.
The specific things to consider here are :

1) I'm only doing a few draw calls to draw the whole screen, using shaders, and I'm not drawing "tile by tile" in a 2D loop

2) The whole map is much bigger than the screen, and the screen can move every frame or so

In that case, how could I draw the fog of war ? I have no issue maintaining on the CPU-side a 2D array giving the fog of war for each tile, but what would be the best way to actually display it dynamically ?
thanks!

Comment: Something I experimented with when another dev asked about fog of war ( http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71934/alpha-blending-use-the-pixel-with-the-smallest-alpha/71961#71961 ) was to create a mesh plane over the scene whose vertex alphas corresponded to visibility values. I then combined those with texture animation in the shader to create animated feathering at the edges of the fog. If that method may be of interest, I can expand it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure of what type of fog you want to display, but if you want to do an AoEII fog, so a black fog, it would be something like that:

Your fog tileset:

[image: Fog tileset]

And your code should be like that (it's pseudocode). Here I blit tile by tile but you can replace with your own technical:

```
Let fog[nTileX][nTileY] be your fog array
    // values: 1 discovered tile and 0 undiscovered

For i = 0; i < nTileX; i++
    For j = 0; j < nTileY; j++
        If fog[i][j] == 1 Then 
            Blit your tile at pos (i, j)
        Endif
    Endfor
Endfor

For i = 0; i < nTileX; i++
    For j = 0; j < nTileY; j++
        If fog[i-1][j] == 0 Then 
            If fog[i][j-1] == 0 Then
                Blit fog tile number 8
            Elseif fog[i][j+1] == 0 Then
                Blit fog tile number 5
            Else
                Blit fog tile number 1
            Endif
        Endif
        If fog[i+1][j] == 0 Then 
            If fog[i][j-1] == 0 Then
                Blit fog tile number 6
            Elseif fog[i][j+1] == 0 Then
                Blit fog tile number 7
            Else
                Blit fog tile number 3
            Endif
        Endif
        If fog[i][j+1] == 0 Then
            Blit fog tile number 2
        Endif
        If fog[i][j-1] == 0 Then
            Blit fog tile number 4
        Endif
    Endfor
Endfor
```

If you want the tiles you already explored but where you are not present to be darkened, and with the building you saw when you explored, you can take a screenshot at each frame, and each new frame you add an alpha filter to it, and then you blit it after filling the screen of black.

Comment: A fog tileset, quite cleaver. Probably how they did in AgeII.